# Ember.js How to intercept and filter parameters passed to Ember.Object.create(params)

Tags: javascript, ember.js

```
App.Person = Ember.Object.extend({
  firstName: "Trek",
});

App.person = App.Person.create({
  firstName: undefined
})

console.log(App.person.get('firstName'));
```

This code will output **undefined**, but I want somehow to intercept setting of property and if it sets to **undefined** keep default value "**Trek**" unchanged.

ember-1.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use computed properties:

```
App.Person = Ember.Object.extend({
  _firstName: 'Trek',
  firstName: function(key, value) {
    if (arguments.length > 1 && typeof value !== 'undefined') {
      this.set('_firstName', value);
    }

    return this.get('_firstName');
  }.property('_firstName')
});

App.person = App.Person.create({
  firstName: undefined
})

console.log(App.person.get('firstName'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a computed property and a default value

```
App.Person = Ember.Object.extend({
    firstNameDefault:'Trek',
    firstName:function(key,value){
        if(arguments.length > 1 && typeof value !== 'undefined'){
            return value
        }
        return this.get('firstNameDefault');
    }.property('firstNameDefault')
});

App.person = App.Person.create({
  firstName: undefined
})

console.log(App.person.get('firstName'));
```